# Conversion from String to Date error appearing on window embedded but not on windows 10

Tags: vb.net, date-conversion, windows-7-embedded

I have a problem which appears on windows7embedded 32bit but not on my windows10 64bit developing desktop. I run the exactly same code.

I have a variable as Date which contains date and time.
Then I put it into a function as string. In the function I modify it while it is a string and then I convert it back to date again. This is where the error appears.

This is the format I use. Its always the format before I convert it:

> dd.MM.yyyy hh:mm:ss

This is the function I use to convert the string, with the named format, into a date:

```
Dim d As Date

d = CDate(strDate)
```

Its one of my first posts, I still have my struggles with programming and thank you in advance.

Comment: Use [`Date.ParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact) or [`Date.TryParseExact()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.tryparseexact) and pass that format as the second argument.

Comment: Thanks for you answer. I still get the error: _Conversion from string "25.09.2019 09:28:36" to type "Date" is not valid._ on the windows 7 embedded device. It works perfectly fine on my windows 10 maschine.

Comment: Please [edit] the question and include your new code. Also, please make sure it's a [repro].

Comment: Could the problem be a simple date format issue?  25.09.2019 isn't a valid US English date, because 25 isn't a valid month.  However, it is perfectly fine in Europe for example.  Are you using the same locale for both systems?

Comment: @gaccardo I use the same format on the other system. both systems run on "dd.MM.yyyy"